# Excel formula to check if items from a comma separated list in one cell exist in a comma separated list in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where every row has two columns, each containing a comma separated list of words or phrases.

```
Column 1                        | Column 2
---------------------------------------------------------
Orange, Pear, Sugar apple, Kiwi | Orange, Sugar apple
Banana, Watermelon, Pomegranate | Strawberry, Banana
```

I'm trying to create a formula that checks if the items listed in Column 2 are a subset of the items listed in Column 1 and outputs `true` or `false`.

In the above example the output should be `true` for Row 1 and `false` for Row 2.

The solutions I tried using the `search` and `find` functions only work if the items in Column 2 are listed in the same sequence, i.e. if Column 2 is a substring of Column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(", " & TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX(XFD:XFD,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)) & ",",", "&A1&",")))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode

[image]

Comment: Upon closer inspection it works in most cases but not every case. When Column 1 is "Apple, Banana, Pear" and Column 2 is "Banana, Pear, Grapefruit" it returns true when it should return false.

Comment: It also incorrectly returns true when Column 1 is "Apple, Banana, Pear" and Column 2 is "Apple, Kiwi, Starfruit". Every item in Column 2 should appear in Column 1 for true to be returned.

Comment: @shanzilla can you confirm you entered the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter? I cannot replicate those results you mention.

Comment: That was it @BigBen, forgot that my ctrl key isn't working, had to use an external keyboard. It's working perfectly now.